Spring boot reactor netty, S3AsyncClient and AsyncResponseTransformer for large file downloads
This is a counterpart of S3AsyncClient and AsyncResponseTransformer maintain back-pressure during download.
It's a very basic spring boot reactive app which streams files from S3.
Here is a basic code snippet:
@GetMapping(path="/{filekey}")
Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ByteBuffer>>> downloadFile(@PathVariable("filekey") String filekey) {    
    GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
      .bucket(s3config.getBucket())
      .key(filekey)
      .build();
    
    return Mono.fromFuture(s3client.getObject(request, AsyncResponseTransformer.toPublisher()))
      .map(response -> {
        checkResult(response.response());
        String filename = getMetadataItem(response.response(),"filename",filekey);            
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, response.response().contentType())
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(response.response().contentLength()))
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"")
          .body(Flux.from(response));
      });
}

Switching to Netty instead of CRT works much better from backpressure point of view.
There is a netty on the spring boot side which I will call reactor-netty and netty on the S3 Client side which I will refer to as s3-netty.
I see that for each request the direct mem consumed by reactor-netty is increased by 8BM which is a cache chunk size (maxOrder=10) and grows up to some number but then stops growing. I guess that's based on the number of reactor-netty threads and pool arenas.
Locally I use windows and hence reactor-netty is using reactor-http-nio. On the server we have linux and hence it uses reactor-http-epoll.
When I create 90 clients downloading 500MB files locally, all clients are slowly getting the chunks (the more clients, the slower) but none of the clients idling, Jmeter shows that  latency is fine.
When I do the same on the server, multiple requests are failing due to latency being over 20secs, i.e. some of requests are getting the data, and some of the requests are waiting for a first byte for a long time.
I am not sure if the bottleneck is S3 Async Client busy with pushing the chunks to reactor-netty, or reactor-netty busy with pushing chunks to clients. But in general I am quite puzzled: both reactor-netty and s3-netty have their own event loops. S3 also has response-writer threads, but if I log something in the Flux I see that the log statement is printed by the aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop, so chunks from s3 are pushed into reactor-netty by the s3-netty event loop threads.
I tried to use .publishOn() dedicated parallel Scheduler but that didn't change anything.
Overall, if the only thing my server does is streaming big files from S3, does it make sense to use reactive/async stuff or should I simply switch back to good old blocking IO and do the chunking manually?
File download takes from 10 to 100seconds based on the number of users.

I answered my counterpart question and switched back to CRT.
As for netty, it seems that by using 8KB chunks the event loops are just too busy dealing with reads/writes which causes bigger latency for newer requests.
